# Cannot see samba server or access samba shares from Windows

Tags: samba, centos7, windows-10, webmin

I've been setting up my home server using `CentOS 7` and `Webmin`. I've installed the `Samba` package / module and configured it, and it has been started.

Now, on my Windows machine running `Windows 10 x64`, I can't see the server in the Network section of explorer. It just isn't listed. However, when I manually enter the server's IP (`\\192.168.1.50`) it does connect. I then login with the only user I have set up for samba, which is qub1, which is linked to the user qub1 in webmin. It then shows the shares I have enabled on the server, which are qub1, homes and Media.

However, when I try to open the `Media` share it gives me an error message saying

```
Windows cannot access \\192.168.1.50\Media
You do not have permission to access \\192.168.1.50\Media. Contact your network administrator to request access.
```

Which is weird, since the user qub1 is the owner of `/home/qub1/media` (where the share is located), and has full read, write and execute permissions.

My Samba config:

```
# This is the main Samba configuration file. For detailed information about the
# options listed here, refer to the smb.conf(5) manual page. Samba has a huge
# number of configurable options, most of which are not shown in this example.
#
# The Official Samba 3.2.x HOWTO and Reference Guide contains step-by-step
# guides for installing, configuring, and using Samba:
# http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba-HOWTO-Collection.pdf
#
# The Samba-3 by Example guide has working examples for smb.conf. This guide is
# generated daily: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba-Guide.pdf
#
# In this file, lines starting with a semicolon (;) or a hash (#) are
# comments and are ignored. This file uses hashes to denote commentary and
# semicolons for parts of the file you may wish to configure.
#
# Note: Run the "testparm" command after modifying this file to check for basic
# syntax errors.
#
#---------------
# Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux) Notes:
#
# Turn the samba_domain_controller Boolean on to allow Samba to use the useradd
# and groupadd family of binaries. Run the following command as the root user to
# turn this Boolean on:
# setsebool -P samba_domain_controller on
#
# Turn the samba_enable_home_dirs Boolean on if you want to share home
# directories via Samba. Run the following command as the root user to turn this
# Boolean on:
# setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on
#
# If you create a new directory, such as a new top-level directory, label it
# with samba_share_t so that SELinux allows Samba to read and write to it. Do
# not label system directories, such as /etc/ and /home/, with samba_share_t, as
# such directories should already have an SELinux label.
#
# Run the "ls -ldZ /path/to/directory" command to view the current SELinux
# label for a given directory.
#
# Set SELinux labels only on files and directories you have created. Use the
# chcon command to temporarily change a label:
# chcon -t samba_share_t /path/to/directory
#
# Changes made via chcon are lost when the file system is relabeled or commands
# such as restorecon are run.
#
# Use the samba_export_all_ro or samba_export_all_rw Boolean to share system
# directories. To share such directories and only allow read-only permissions:
# setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro on
# To share such directories and allow read and write permissions:
# setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on
#
# To run scripts (preexec/root prexec/print command/...), copy them to the
# /var/lib/samba/scripts/ directory so that SELinux will allow smbd to run them.
# Note that if you move the scripts to /var/lib/samba/scripts/, they retain
# their existing SELinux labels, which may be labels that SELinux does not allow
# smbd to run. Copying the scripts will result in the correct SELinux labels.
# Run the "restorecon -R -v /var/lib/samba/scripts" command as the root user to
# apply the correct SELinux labels to these files.
#
#--------------
#
#======================= Global Settings =====================================

[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    netbios name = qub1-server
    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    os level = 20
    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    max log size = 50

# ----------------------- Network-Related Options -------------------------
#
# workgroup = the Windows NT domain name or workgroup name, for example, MYGROUP.
#
# server string = the equivalent of the Windows NT Description field.
#
# netbios name = used to specify a server name that is not tied to the hostname.
#
# interfaces = used to configure Samba to listen on multiple network interfaces.
# If you have multiple interfaces, you can use the "interfaces =" option to
# configure which of those interfaces Samba listens on. Never omit the localhost
# interface (lo).
#
# hosts allow = the hosts allowed to connect. This option can also be used on a
# per-share basis.
#
# hosts deny = the hosts not allowed to connect. This option can also be used on
# a per-share basis.
#
# max protocol = used to define the supported protocol. The default is NT1. You
# can set it to SMB2 if you want experimental SMB2 support.
#

;   netbios name = MYSERVER

;   interfaces = lo eth0 192.168.12.2/24 192.168.13.2/24
;   hosts allow = 127. 192.168.12. 192.168.13.

;   max protocol = SMB2

# --------------------------- Logging Options -----------------------------
#
# log file = specify where log files are written to and how they are split.
#
# max log size = specify the maximum size log files are allowed to reach. Log
# files are rotated when they reach the size specified with "max log size".
#

    # log files split per-machine:
    # maximum size of 50KB per log file, then rotate:

# ----------------------- Standalone Server Options ------------------------
#
# security = the mode Samba runs in. This can be set to user, share
# (deprecated), or server (deprecated).
#
# passdb backend = the backend used to store user information in. New
# installations should use either tdbsam or ldapsam. No additional configuration
# is required for tdbsam. The "smbpasswd" utility is available for backwards
# compatibility.
#



# ----------------------- Domain Members Options ------------------------
#
# security = must be set to domain or ads.
#
# passdb backend = the backend used to store user information in. New
# installations should use either tdbsam or ldapsam. No additional configuration
# is required for tdbsam. The "smbpasswd" utility is available for backwards
# compatibility.
#
# realm = only use the realm option when the "security = ads" option is set.
# The realm option specifies the Active Directory realm the host is a part of.
#
# password server = only use this option when the "security = server"
# option is set, or if you cannot use DNS to locate a Domain Controller. The
# argument list can include My_PDC_Name, [My_BDC_Name], and [My_Next_BDC_Name]:
#
# password server = My_PDC_Name [My_BDC_Name] [My_Next_BDC_Name]
#
# Use "password server = *" to automatically locate Domain Controllers.

;   security = domain
;   passdb backend = tdbsam
;   realm = MY_REALM

;   password server = <NT-Server-Name>

# ----------------------- Domain Controller Options ------------------------
#
# security = must be set to user for domain controllers.
#
# passdb backend = the backend used to store user information in. New
# installations should use either tdbsam or ldapsam. No additional configuration
# is required for tdbsam. The "smbpasswd" utility is available for backwards
# compatibility.
#
# domain master = specifies Samba to be the Domain Master Browser, allowing
# Samba to collate browse lists between subnets. Do not use the "domain master"
# option if you already have a Windows NT domain controller performing this task.
#
# domain logons = allows Samba to provide a network logon service for Windows
# workstations.
#
# logon script = specifies a script to run at login time on the client. These
# scripts must be provided in a share named NETLOGON.
#
# logon path = specifies (with a UNC path) where user profiles are stored.
#
#
;   security = user
;   passdb backend = tdbsam

;   domain master = yes
;   domain logons = yes

    # the following login script name is determined by the machine name
    # (%m):
;   logon script = %m.bat
    # the following login script name is determined by the UNIX user used:
;   logon script = %u.bat
;   logon path = \\%L\Profiles\%u
    # use an empty path to disable profile support:
;   logon path =

    # various scripts can be used on a domain controller or a stand-alone
    # machine to add or delete corresponding UNIX accounts:

;   add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd "%u" -n -g users
;   add group script = /usr/sbin/groupadd "%g"
;   add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -n -c "Workstation (%u)" -M -d /nohome -s /bin/false "%u"
;   delete user script = /usr/sbin/userdel "%u"
;   delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/userdel "%u" "%g"
;   delete group script = /usr/sbin/groupdel "%g"


# ----------------------- Browser Control Options ----------------------------
#
# local master = when set to no, Samba does not become the master browser on
# your network. When set to yes, normal election rules apply.
#
# os level = determines the precedence the server has in master browser
# elections. The default value should be reasonable.
#
# preferred master = when set to yes, Samba forces a local browser election at
# start up (and gives itself a slightly higher chance of winning the election).
#
;   local master = no
;   os level = 33
;   preferred master = yes

#----------------------------- Name Resolution -------------------------------
#
# This section details the support for the Windows Internet Name Service (WINS).
#
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS server or a WINS client, but not both.
#
# wins support = when set to yes, the NMBD component of Samba enables its WINS
# server.
#
# wins server = tells the NMBD component of Samba to be a WINS client.
#
# wins proxy = when set to yes, Samba answers name resolution queries on behalf
# of a non WINS capable client. For this to work, there must be at least one
# WINS server on the network. The default is no.
#
# dns proxy = when set to yes, Samba attempts to resolve NetBIOS names via DNS
# nslookups.

;   wins support = yes
;   wins server = w.x.y.z
;   wins proxy = yes

;   dns proxy = yes

# --------------------------- Printing Options -----------------------------
#
# The options in this section allow you to configure a non-default printing
# system.
#
# load printers = when set you yes, the list of printers is automatically
# loaded, rather than setting them up individually.
#
# cups options = allows you to pass options to the CUPS library. Setting this
# option to raw, for example, allows you to use drivers on your Windows clients.
#
# printcap name = used to specify an alternative printcap file.
#


;   printcap name = /etc/printcap
    # obtain a list of printers automatically on UNIX System V systems:
;   printcap name = lpstat
;   printing = cups

# --------------------------- File System Options ---------------------------
#
# The options in this section can be un-commented if the file system supports
# extended attributes, and those attributes are enabled (usually via the
# "user_xattr" mount option). These options allow the administrator to specify
# that DOS attributes are stored in extended attributes and also make sure that
# Samba does not change the permission bits.
#
# Note: These options can be used on a per-share basis. Setting them globally
# (in the [global] section) makes them the default for all shares.

;   map archive = no
;   map hidden = no
;   map read only = no
;   map system = no
;   store dos attributes = yes


#============================ Share Definitions ==============================

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    writeable = yes
;   valid users = %S
;   valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    browseable = no
    guest ok = no
    writable = no
    printable = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons:
;   [netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /var/lib/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   writable = no
;   share modes = no

# Un-comment the following to provide a specific roving profile share.
# The default is to use the user's home directory:
;   [Profiles]
;   path = /var/lib/samba/profiles
;   browseable = no
;   guest ok = yes

# A publicly accessible directory that is read only, except for users in the
# "staff" group (which have write permissions):
;   [public]
;   comment = Public Stuff
;   path = /home/samba
;   public = yes
;   writable = yes
;   printable = no
;   write list = +staff

[Media]
    path = /home/qub1/media
```

So my questions actually boil down to:

- How can I get the samba server to show up in the network section on Windows?
- How can I access the shares on my samba server?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems as you haven't opened the necessary ports on the CentOS machine.

Try issuing the following commands:

- `firewall-cmd --add-service=samba`
- `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=samba`
- `service smb restart`

Then, retry to connect to the share from the Windows machine.

Comment: I have opened the ports, and I still cannot connect. I've even rebooted my router and all involved computers and still nothing :(

Comment: I did some digging and I found the problem lies with SELinux blocking any requests I make from windows. I have been able to access the shares when setting SELinux to permissive. Are there any downsides to this approach, i.e. security issues I need to be aware of?

Comment: SELINUX is an important security tools, so it should be left enabled. Can you show the output of `cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow` ?

Comment: It can't find audit2allow, also can't install it using `yum install audit2allow`

Comment: Issue `yum whatprovides */audit2allow` to identify and install the correct package.